# INSERT SELECT with condition

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm trying to do a INSERT SELECT with condition but smthg seems to be wrong. I get an 1064 error for wrong syntax.

Here is the query  :

```
INSERT INTO  `db1`.`table`.`field` (

SELECT a.`field1` , a.`field2` 
FROM  `db2`.`table1` a,  `db2`.`table2` b
WHERE a.`field1` = b.`field1` 
AND b.`field2` =  'value'
)

WHERE a.`field1` =  `db1`.`table1`.`field1`
```

Thank in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for the insert select is :

```
INSERT california_authors (au_id, au_lname, au_fname)
SELECT au_id, au_lname, au_fname
FROM authors
WHERE State = 'CA'
```

so in you case it like

```
  INSERT INTO  `db1`.`table` (.... field list ...)
  select 
    ... col for select .....
  from table 
  where ... where condition ....
```

Comment: not working for me; seems still to have a problem with the second where clause (for insert); wrong syntax

Comment: okay then ! php will do it anyway, was just trying to do it all mysql :)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for INSERT INTO is usually

```
INSERT INTO myTable (field1,field2,...,fieldN)
SELECT field1,field2,etc FROM myTable WHERE condition
```

You need to simplify your queries and think through what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

My question was bad. In this case it is not Insert but an Update query which is needed